# How to get around awsnap ag-grid with Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Ag-Grid breaks after 200k rows and I am getting a Chrome error.

When I go:

```
 const data = grid.data;
```

then do a post call with it or some data processing, I get an aw snap from Chrome.

Has anyone ever experienced this or do you have a workaround?

Comment: An "aw snap" is usually because the tab runs out of memory and crashes, right? So it would be helpful to know what you are trying to do with the data.

I suspect that maybe Chrome devtools is having a hard time dealing with the large amount of data as well. Is the 200k row array the only load on devtools? Do you also have a lot of console.log lines or are you trying to performance profile, or log the array to the watch list, or anything else crazy?

Comment: Thanks @GregL for you suggestion. lots of things to consider. Manually transform data . Does an instance of a chrome tab keep track of all console.logs? Does chrome do garbage collection?